# How to mock module in different ways in different tests in the same test file in Jest?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs, mocking

Currently I have this:

```
jest.mock('my/hook', () => () => false)
```

I want my custom React hook module to return `false` in every test by default, but in a few tests I want it to return true.

The hook is implemented essentially like this:

```
function useMyHook(key) {
  switch (key) {
    case 'foo':
    case 'bar':
      return true
    default:
      return false
  }
}
```

I am using the hook several times in my component, once for the `foo` key and once for the `bar` key. I want it to return false for both keys by default.

But for a few tests I want the `foo` key to return true, and for other tests I want the `bar` key to return true.

I tried that by doing this in the specific test, but it didn't do anything:

```
it('should do x', () => {
  jest.doMock('my/hook', () => (key) => {
    if (key == 'foo') {
      return true
    }
  })
  // ... rest of test
})
```

How do I customize module mocks on a per-test basis in Jest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jest.doMock` alone can't do anything because a module that depends on it has been already imported earlier. It should be re-imported after that, with module cache discarded with either `jest.resetModules` or `jest.isolateModules`:

```
beforeEach(() => {
  jest.resetModules();
});

it('should do x', () => {
  jest.doMock('my/hook', ...)
  require('module that depends on hook');
  // ... rest of test
})
```

Since it's a function that needs to be mocked differently, a better way is to mock the implementation with Jest spies instead of plain functions:

```
jest.mock('my/hook', () => jest.fn(() => false))
...
it('should do x', () => {
  hook.mockReturnValueOnce(true);
  // ... rest of test
})
```